# I need some help styling my donut_chart from the Highcharts library

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to add some border radius and gradient color to the bars in my  donut chart from the Highcharts library. Images of both the expected chart and what I have managed to create are attached, along with my code.

Expected chart:
[image]

My current progress:
[image]

```
 $(function() {
             var data = < %= raw @array_color.to_json % > ;
             var total_project_count = < %= @total_project_count % >
                 var total_project_text = `Totatl Projects<br/>${total_project_count}`
             var total_project_text = `<span class="project_count_text">TOTAL PROJECTS</span><br/><span class="project_count_dummy">""</span><br/><span class="project_count_count">${total_project_count}</span>`
             var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                     renderTo: 'container',
                     type: 'pie',
                 },
                 credits: false,
                 plotOptions: {
                     pie: {
                         borderWidth: 6,
                         innerSize: '80%',
                         // borderColor: null, 
                         slicedOffset: 5,
                         stacking: 'normal',
                         dataLabels: {
                             connectorWidth: 2
                         },
                         allowPointSelect: true,
                         cursor: 'pointer',
                         point: {
                             events: {
                                 click: function(event) {
                                     var options = this.options;
                                     update_rag(options.status);
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     },
                 },
                 title: {
                     verticalAlign: 'middle',
                     floating: true,
                     text: total_project_text,
                 },
                 series: [{
                     data: data,
                 }, ],
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 11, the `borderRadius` property appeared that allows you to round elements.

And to the color table, apart from the strings with hex values, you can also pass `Highcharts.GradientColorObject` with which you can set the gradient, but I'm not sure if you will be able to reproduce exactly as in the picture you sent.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ocrzyaj/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.borderRadius 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors